# Using jquery find() to select input by class

Tags: jquery, forms, class, input, find

I have a script which validates each stage of a form and adds a tick or cross to each section if the validation is without errors or not.

Here is my code:

```
var error = 1;
var hasError = false;
$('.edit_artist').children(':nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ')').find('input:not(button)').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;
                if(valueLength == '') {
                    hasError = true;    
                }
```

I dont want the validation to occur on all input fields, so I want to be able to validate inputs by class. Is there a way of finding inputs by class or would I need to go down another route to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This shows very little effort - stuff like this can be found with a relatively small amount of time on the jQuery site - and you should be spending time there anyway, if you're trying to do things in jQuery.

Comment: I have spent a good amount of time looking for a way to select inputs by class, but methods I have found have been unsuccessful or hard to find. Furthermore I wouldnt take the time to ask a question on here, if I haven't researched it in detail before.

Comment: First entry on the google search for `jquery class selector` is hard to find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find an element based on its `class`, and while excluding `button` elements:

```
$(selector).find('input.className:not("button")');
```

Or, a more verbose manner:

```
$(selector).find('input:not("button")').filter(
     function(){
         return $(this).hasClass('className')
     });
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).